# How to perform `ssh-copy-id` command in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, ssh, nestjs, ssh-keys

I am using NestJS and I want to automatize the creation and installation of ssh keys into a remote server.
I am actually using `node-ssh` to perform `ssh` operation and authenticate into remote servers, but I can't find any solution with this or other libraries that allows me to:

- Create a SSH key pair.
- Install the key into the remote server.

Now I am doing this way, but I really would like to use a unique ssh agent in my application, and I would like to avoid using `ssh-pass`

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec(`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f KEY_PATH`);
exec(`ssh-pass -p PASSWORD ssh-copy-id USERNAME@HOST -p PORT -i KEY_PATH`);
```